# Program catches FileNotFoundException even though the file is in the correct directory

Tags: filenotfoundexception, ioexception, file-not-found

I am writing a program for my CS class and I have to read the text from the data.txt file and if, for whatever reason that file is not there, I am supposed to throw an IOE exception and print out "File not found".

```
 try{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
    String temp;
    int n = 0;
    ...
```

and

```
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

but when I run the program, all I get is the "File not found" but the data.txt file is in that folder along with the java program file. Can anyone please help me with how I can make the program see the data.txt file

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps try `cd`'ing to the directory when you run the program, or specify a full path

Comment: I tried the full path thing, doesn't work either for whatever reason..

Comment: Hmm perhaps print the exception in full, and check the permissions maybe

Comment: Could you help me with this please? I'm kind of new to programming and usually never had a need to do that since I never encountered such a problem.